# Cascade UPDATE on a table on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update

I'm a newbie here and with PostgreSQL as well. I have two different boolean columns in two different tables. When I update my boolean column  as `true` in `tableone`, I must also set a boolean column in `tabletwo` to `true`.

For example: (these are related by `sipariskod`)

```
UPDATE tabletwo 
SET kalemonay = tableone.sonaydurum 
FROM  tableone 
WHERE tabletwo.sipariskod='10'
```

I used this SQL query, but it didn't work. I don't know why. :(

I need a function or trigger to execute when I update `tableone`'s boolean to also update the boolean in `tabletwo`- if it exists with the same `sipariskod`.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: In what way diodn't work? Alas, we're not telepathic and only know what you tell us. Please *edit your question* to describe what happens (or doesn't happen) including any error messages you get.

Comment: How are tabletwo and tableone realted? Might be best solved with a foreign key and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution cannot be guessed from the limited information you provided.

In any case, your query fails on principal. There is no condition connecting the two tables, so it results in an expensive and nonsensical [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) - the same as a `CROSS JOIN`. Effectively, instead of justa single update, you get one for *every* row in `tableone`, and it is not defined which of these comes last to have a lasting effect.

Since you provided:

> (these are related by sipariskod)

.. your query could look like this:

```
UPDATE tabletwo t2
SET    kalemonay = t1.sonaydurum 
FROM   tableone t1
WHERE  t2.sipariskod = t1.sipariskod
AND    t1.??? = ???
```

But this statement would look **different inside a trigger function** where you can use the `NEW` object. For instance, inside a **trigger** function for a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo
AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE ON tableone
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo();
```

The **trigger function** could look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

IF NEW.sonaydurum IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.sonaydurum THEN
   UPDATE tabletwo t2
   SET    kalemonay = NEW.sonaydurum 
   WHERE  t2.sipariskod = NEW.sipariskod;
   AND    kalemonay IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.sonaydurum;
END IF;

RETURN NULL;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I added some checks to avoid empty updates.

#### Foreign key

But the whole thing *might* be cleaner with a [foreign key constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. Depends on the details.
You'd have to clear up offending values from the referencing table, and create a unique (or primary) index on the referenced column(s), before you can create the foreign key. Are you aware that a foreign key can be built on *multiple columns*?

Comment: Hi Erwin Sorry for limited information. i tried query but it didnt work :( 
this is my database diagram as you can see
http://imageshack.us/a/img402/9474/erdiagramp.png
i think the cleaner solution must be foreign key but there are many records in table and they are true or false the foreign key value must be unique.how could i relation two boolean cell thank for your help and your kindness.

Comment: Please **edit** your question with what you tried and how it failed and what you are trying to explain in this comment. If you got an error message copy it into your question. Your explanation here is ambiguous. A record cannot be `TRUE`, only a field / column can.